# RangeError: Invalid array length NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I have some code, where I am trying to chart stock data. The values are being successfully pulled in but I am getting an error when trying to chart.

Looking specifically at the chart function. when I use console.log(hist); and console.log(q) I am able to get the respective values from them.

```
const asciichart = require("asciichart");
const ora = require("ora");
const chalk = require("chalk");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const { IEXCloudClient } = require("node-iex-cloud");
const { history } = require("yahoo-stocks"); //Special Thanks to: Fabian Beuke aka Madnight (https://github.com/madnight)
const { interpolateArray } = require("array-interpolatejs");
const { toHumanString } = require("human-readable-numbers");
const { identity, defaultTo, pipe } = require("lodash/fp");
const { tail, flatMap } = require("lodash/fp");
const { compact, map } = require("lodash/fp");

module.exports = args => {
  let symbol = args.symbol || args.s;

  const throbber = ora().start();
  const width = defaultTo(14);
  const height = defaultTo(80);
  const range = defaultTo("5y");
  const humanString = i => (i ? toHumanString(i).replace("G", "B") : null);

  const iex = new IEXCloudClient(fetch, {
    publishable: "pk_abcxyzdedfg"
  });

  const errorHandler = () => {
    console.log(chalk.red("Error. Could not find symbol: " + symbol));
    process.exit(1);
  };

  const getHist = async () => {
    return await history(symbol.toUpperCase(), {
      interval: "1m",
      range: range
    }).catch(errorHandler);
  };

  const getQuote = async i => {
    return await iex
      .symbols(i)
      .batch("quote")
      .catch(errorHandler);
  };

  const chart = async () => {
    try {
      const [hist, qt] = await Promise.all([getHist(), getQuote(symbol)]);
      const chart = pipe(
        map(identity),
        tail,
        flatMap(map("close")),
        interpolateArray(width),
        compact,
        x => asciichart.plot(x, { height: height })
      )(hist);
      console.log(hist);
      const q = map("quote")(qt)[0];
      console.log(q);
      console.log(chart);
      console.log(q.companyName)
      console.log(
        " ".repeat(15) +
          (q.companyName +
            " " +
            " chart. Latest Price: $" +
            q.latestPrice +
            " | MktCap: " +
            humanString(q.marketCap))
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  chart();

  throbber.succeed(`${chalk.green("All Done")}`);
};
```

but when I use console.log(chart); I end up with this error:

```
RangeError: Invalid array length
    at Object.exports.plot (C:\Users\Saksham\Projects\stock-cli\node_modules\asciichart\asciichart.js:29:22) 
    at x (C:\Users\Saksham\Projects\stock-cli\cmds\chart.js:54:25)
    at C:\Users\Saksham\Projects\stock-cli\node_modules\lodash\lodash.min.js:49:144
    at chart (C:\Users\Saksham\Projects\stock-cli\cmds\chart.js:55:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occured at `asciichart.plot(x, { height: height })`, so the array length error implies that `x` is not a proper array.

If the code you posted is your full code, it appears that your `x` is undefined, which would cause the Invalid array length error as asciichart.plot requires first parameter to be an array